# Deleted jupyter notebook cell - is there a way to get back to the code from an object still in memory?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to get a LIME interpreter working all day. Finally got the syntax right, but managed to delete the jupyter notebook cell defining the explainer. The object is still in memory, so I can call the object and get results, but now I can't get back to the actual code. The code should be something like this:

```
explainer = lime.lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(train, feature_names=boston.feature_names, class_names=['price'], categorical_features=categorical_features, verbose=True, mode='regression')
```

Is there any way to inspect the explainer object that is in memory, and print the "settings" that were used to create it?

I have tried just running

```
explainer
```

or

```
print(explainer)
```

but both just return

```
<lime.lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer object at 0x000001B5F1BAD860>
```

Comment: I managed to get some info from using import inspect
print(inspect.getmembers(explainer))

Comment: In jupyter you can try 'undo' under the edit menu item. Otherwise you can use `%hist` to view the command history of your current session. Otherwise you can try `explainer.__dict__` to view all of its variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your IPython kernel is still running, you can use IPython's line magic to view all commands executed in that kernel (this should include the code used to define your lime explainer).

The appropriate command for this is [`%history`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-history) (alias `%hist`).

To execute, simply run that command in a new cell in the appropriate notebook.

Comment: Thank you, that worked a lot better than the inspect approach!